# Show that there exists $L \in \mathbb{R}_+^*$ such that for all $x \in [a,b]$ $|g(x) - c| \leq L|x - c|^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, inequality

I encountered an exercise from the admission exam for the Moroccan preparatory class Al-Zahrawi where I faced a small problem with question 4. I was able to answer the question, but the statement forced us to use the Mean Value Theorem on $f'$ and $f$, which I did not know how to do.

The statement is as follows:

Let $f$ be a $C^2$ function on an interval $[a,b]$ with $f(a) > 0$ and $f(b) < 0$, and for all $x \in [a,b]$, $f'(x) < 0$ and $f''(x) > 0$.

Part 1:

1. Show that there exists a unique $c \in [a,b]$ such that $f(c) = 0$.
2. For $t \in [a,b]$, determine the coordinates of the point of intersection between the tangent at the point of abscissa t and the x-axis.
3. We introduce $g(x) = x - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$. Study the variations of $g$.
4. We admit the existence of $M, \ m \in \mathbb{R}_+^*$ such that for all $x \in [a,b]$, $|f''(x)| \le M \text{ and } |f'(x)| \geq m$.. By successively applying the Mean Value Theorem to $f$ and $f'$, show that there exists $L \in \mathbb{R}_+^*$ such that for all $x \in [a,b]$ $|g(x) - c| \leq L|x - c|^2$.

My approach for question 4 without applying the Mean Value Theorem to $f'$ is as follows:

Let $x \in [a,b]$. We have:

$g'(x) = \frac{f''(x)f(x)}{(f'(x))^2}$.

Since $f$ is $C^1$ on $[a,b]$ and particularly on an interval with boundaries $c$ and $x$, according to the Mean Value Theorem:

$\exists \alpha \in [c, x] \text{ or } [x, c] \ | \ f'(\alpha)(x - c) = f(x) - f(c)$.

Therefore:

$\exists \alpha \in [c, x]\text{ or } [x, c]  | g'(x) = \frac{f''(x)f'(\alpha)(x - c)}{(f'(x))^2}$.

However:

$\alpha > a \Rightarrow 0 > f'(\alpha) > f'(a)$.

Therefore:

$|f'(a)| > |f'(\alpha)|$.

Therefore:

$\left| \frac{f''(x)f'(a)(x - c)}{(f'(x))^2} \right| > |g'(x)|$.

However:

$|f''(x)| \le M \text{ and } |f'(x)| \geq m$.

Therefore:

$\frac{M}{m^2}|f'(a)||x - c| > \left| \frac{f''(x)f'(a)(x - c)}{(f'(x))^2} \right| > |g'(x)|$.

Conclusion:

$\exists L \in \mathbb{R}_+^* | \ \forall x \in [a,b] : \ |g'(x)| \le L|x - c|$.

However:

Since $g$ is $C^1$ on $[a,b]$ and particularly on an interval with boundaries $c$ and $x$, according to the Mean Value Theorem:

$\exists \beta \in [c, x] \text{ or } [x, c] \ | \ g'(\beta)(x - c) = g(x) - g(c) = g(x) - c$.

Therefore:

$\exists L \in \mathbb{R}_+^* | \ \forall x \in [a,b] : \ |g(x) - c| \le L|x - c||\beta - c|$.

It can be easily shown by case disjunction that: $|\beta - c| \le |x - c|$.

Therefore:

$\exists L \in \mathbb{R}_+^* | \ \forall x \in [a,b] : \ |g(x) - c| \le L|x - c|^2$.

Comment: What is $\Bbb R_+^*$?

Comment: So.... did you have a question to ask?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Show the inequality by successively applying the Mean Value Theorem to f and f′, I think I was quite clear in the introduction of the statement; my demonstration was based on the use of the Mean Value Theorem on f and g, not f'. In a real situation, I would not have received full marks.

Comment: @PaulSinclair $\mathbb{R}_+^*$ is the set of strictly positive reals, generally in a field K, K* means without the neutral element of addition, in our case 0.

Comment: That would have been my assumption, except now I am extremely curious how $f$ can both satisfy $f'(x) < 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, but also satisfy that there is an $m \in \Bbb R^*_+$ with $f'(x) \ge m$ for all $x$. It seems a little fishy to me....

Comment: @PaulSinclair You are right in the statement, I forgot to add the absolute value. It should be $|f''(x)| \le M \text{ and } |f'(x)| \geq m$ however, in my proof I used the correct definition of f